# is Visual Studio License required for SSDT 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Is Visual Studio license required if I want to use just SSDT (SSIS part of SQL Server Data Tools)?  I was wondering to install VS2017 or VS2019 as they have PowerQuery Connectors.

Comment: These questions are off topic for [so]. All the information, however, is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15): [SSDT 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#ssdt-for-visual-studio-2017), [SSDT 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#ssdt-for-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: License is not required, download and install VS2019 Community Edition

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because licencing issues are off-topic.